# Run rq as daemon on server

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix

In python, I am using `rq` for the use of background processes. But as I am running same thing on my server also, I want it to run as daemon, apart from unix command does `rq` provides something to make it daemon, like in ruby we have gem called `sidekiq`, it provides all the option for running environment, log file or daemon also.

I tried unix command `rqworker &` but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `nohup rq worker &` will fit your needs (it will work in the server even if you close the `ssh` connection).

But if you really want to run your program as a daemon, have a look to:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/